# SSIS Derived Column Expression

Tags: sql, ssis

I have below derived expression for timestamp in SSIS

```
(DT_DBTIME)(SUBSTRING([Column 11],1,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([Column 11],3,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([Column 11],5,2))
```

but it's not taking null values so I tried this one

```
ISNULL ( [Column 11] ) ? "000000" : (DT_DBTIME)(SUBSTRING([Column 11],1,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([Column 11],3,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([Column 11],5,2))
```

but still its not working.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: can you provide more details what do you mean by _"it's not taking for null values"_ and _"still its not working"_ do you have an error or a wrong result, if you make your question clear you will increase the chance to have an answer

Comment: try this workaround :https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918038

Comment: I have a column with time datatype with values like 231230, 124532, 000000, etc when i try to use this (DT_DBTIME)(SUBSTRING([Column 11],1,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([Column 11],3,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([Column 11],5,2)) it works fine. But when the column has null values in it the expression fails. So to overcome this null i used this expression ISNULL ( [Column 11] ) ? "000000" : (DT_DBTIME)(SUBSTRING([Column 11],1,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([Column 11],3,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([Column 11],5,2)) . but when i try this it throws error.

Comment: Error at Load Table [Derived Column [876]]: Computing the expression "ISNULL ( [Column 11] ) ? "000000" : (DT_DBTIME)(SUBSTRING([Column 11],1,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([Column 11],3,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([Column 11],5,2)) " failed with error code 0xC00470A0. The expression may have errors, such as divide by zero, that cannot be detected at parse time, or there may be an out-of-memory error.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you posted in the question is a bit misleading.

The actual error produced in SSDT is :

> The data types "DT_WSTR" and "DT_DBTIME" are incompatible for the
>   conditional operator. The operand types cannot be implicitly cast into
>   compatible types for the conditional operation. To perform this
>   operation, one or both operands need to be explicitly cast with a cast
>   operator.

and ofcourse the one you posted at the end:

> Error at Data Flow Task [Derived Column [18]]: Computing the
>   expression "(ISNULL([Column 0]) ? "000000" : (DT_DBTIME)
>   (SUBSTRING([Column 0],1,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([Column 0],3,2) + ":" +
>   SUBSTRING([Column 0],5,2)))" failed with error code 0xC00470A0. The
>   expression may have errors, such as divide by zero, that cannot be
>   detected at parse time, or there may be an out-of-memory error.

In your case this simply means that you cannot define (DT_DBTIME) to one part of the conditional operation,

**Else Part**

> : (DT_DBTIME)(SUBSTRING([Column 11],1,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([Column
>   11],3,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([Column 11],5,2))

leaving the other part as "DT_WSTR"

**IF Part**

> ISNULL ( [Column 11] ) ? "000000"

So the correct Transformation rule should be:

> (DT_DBTIME)(IS( [Column 11] ) ? "000000" : (SUBSTRING([Column 11],1,2)
>   + ":" + SUBSTRING([Column 11],3,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([Column 11],5,2)))